# TinyMCE inside JavaScript Pop-up

Tags: tinymce

I have got problem with TinyMCE when TinyMCE is in Pop-up. Look on my explanation of this problem.

This code is in my JSON pop-up

```
<!-- TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "simple"
    });
</script>
<!-- Gets replaced with TinyMCE, remember HTML in a textarea should be encoded -->
<textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="8" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
        Pełny opis...
    </textarea>
<br />
```

When pop-up show first time you can see this editor

[image]

When pop-up show second time you can see this editor

[image]

In my opinion problem is here (only once is working this JS)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "simple"
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case you see the textarea html element. This is probably because of the fact that you didn't shut down tinymce correctly when closing the first pop-up.
What happened behind the curtain is that the html structures are gone, but tinymce still got the editor instance registred and won't open up a new one with the same id when you reopen the pop-up. Solution here is to shut down tinymce when closing the pop-up.

To shut down an editor instance use:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'your_editor_id');
```

To reinitialize use

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'your_editor_id');
```

Tinymce takes as editor id the id of the source html element (your textarea). In case there is none "content" is the default.